# how to jump to a newline in StarUML

Tags: uml, newline, staruml

I have been using StarUML, and I'm creating an activity diagram but I want to add a new line inside an action node, How would I do that?

Comment: Without knowing that tool try the usual suspects: Ctrl, Shift and Alt with return. Also try copy/paste from somewhere.

Comment: @ThomasKilian i did try all of that

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't create a new line with Return but you can `format` the `Node`.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> or `Format->Word Wrap` in the `ContextMenu`

If the Action-Node is to small the text after a space will wrap into the next line.

Comment: I LOVE YOU @michael-seiler

Comment: Is there a way to make this behavior default for all new nodes?

Answer (score 1):

Click the node you want to apply a new line, then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>.

Now this isn't exactly adding a new line but makes the node flexible so you can decide it's size.